# matlab regexprep

Tags: matlab

How to use matlab regexprep , for multiple expression and replacements?

```
file='http:xxx/sys/tags/Rel/total';
```

I want to replace  'sys' with sys1 and 'total' with 'total1'. For a single expression a replacement it works like this:

```
strrep(file,'sys', 'sys1')
```

and want to have like

```
strrep(file,'sys','sys1','total','total1') .
```

I know this doesn't work for `strrep`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just issue the command twice?

```
file = 'http:xxx/sys/tags/Rel/total';

file = strrep(file,'sys','sys1')
strrep(file,'total','total1')
```

Comment: Helo Rody, thanks for your response but my intention is not to issue the command twice. i want to replace 2 of the expressions at thesame time and i have to use like 'evalc(strrep(file,exp,rep,exp,rep))'. Any idea with regexprep?  thanks

Comment: @bstar: "I have to" is never a good reason. Why would two passes be bad?

Answer (score 0):

To solve it you need *substitute functionality* with regex, try to find in matlab's regexes something similar to this in php:

```
$string = 'http:xxx/sys/tags/Rel/total';
preg_replace('/http:(.*?)\//', 'http:${1}1/', $string);
```

`${1}` means 1st match group, that is what in parenthesis, `(.*?)`.

`http:(.*?)\/` - match pattern

`http:${1}1/`  - replace pattern with second 1 as you wish to add (first 1 is a group number)

`http:xxx/sys/tags/Rel/total`  - input string

The secret is that whatever is matched by `(.*?)` (whether *xxx* or *yyyy* or *1234*) will be inserted instead of `${1}` in replace pattern, and then replace instead of old stuff into the input string. Welcome to see more examples on [substitute functionality](http://extract-web-data.com/regex-in-php/#replace) in php.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the help page for `regexprep`, you can specify pairs of patterns and replacements like this:

```
file='http:xxx/sys/tags/Rel/total';
regexprep(file, {'sys' 'total'}, {'sys1' 'total1'})

ans =
http:xxx/sys1/tags/Rel/total1
```

It is even possible to use tokens, should you be able to define a match pattern for everything you want to replace:

```
regexprep(file, '/([st][yo][^/$]*)', '/$11')

ans =
http:xxx/sys1/tags/Rel/total1
```

However, care must be taken with the first approach under certain circumstances, because MATLAB replaces the pairs one after another. That is to say if, say, the first pattern matches a string and replaces it with something that is subsequently matched by a later pattern, then that will also be replaced by the later replacement, even though it might not have matched the later pattern in the original string.

Example:

```
regexprep('This\is{not}LaTeX.', {'\\' '([{}])'}, {'\\textbackslash{}' '\\$1'})

ans =
This\textbackslash\{\}is\{not\}LaTeX.

=> This\{}is{not}LaTeX.
```

and

```
regexprep('This\is{not}LaTeX.', {'([{}])' '\\'}, {'\\$1' '\\textbackslash{}'})

ans =
This\textbackslash{}is\textbackslash{}{not\textbackslash{}}LaTeX.

=> This\is\not\LaTeX.
```

Both results are unintended, and there seems to be no way around this with consecutive replacements instead of simultaneous ones.